# In ReactJS, rendering breaks after using a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the App Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getMovies } from './Files/FakeMovieAPI';
import ItemsNumbers from './Pagination/ItemsNumber';
import Table from './Pagination/Table';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 className="d-inline bg-success"> Motion Pictures Stall </h2>
        <Table movies={this.state.movies} />
        <ItemsNumbers items={this.state.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The ItemsNumbers Component: I wish to use this component to count the numbers of items in the movies(which is being passed as a props) and return the count.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ItemsNumber extends Component {
    state = {
        movies: this.props
    }
    count = 0;
    ItemsCounting = () =>{
        const length = this.state.movies.length()
        console.log(length)
    }

    render(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.ItemsCounting()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ItemsNumber;
```

The FakeMovieAPI file:

```
const Movies = [
  {
    id: 'm7pbc81a',
    title: 'Matrix',
    Year: 1999,
    genre: { id: '193x', name: 'Sci-fi' },
    ratings: 8.7,
    cost: 15
  },
....... 
]
export function getMovies() {
  return Movies;
}
```

Now the errors I am facing: (passing a link to the screenshot error)

> TypeError: this.state.movies.length is not a function
> ItemsNumber.ItemsCounting
> http://localhost:3000/main.577acc89bd7fb431ffe6.hot-update.js:32:40
> this.count = 0;
> this.ItemsCounting = () => {
> const length = this.state.movies.length();
> ^
> console.log(length);
> };
> }
> View source
> ItemsNumber.render
> http://localhost:3000/main.577acc89bd7fb431ffe6.hot-update.js:39:22
>
> render(props) {
> return /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["jsxDEV"])("div", {
> children: this.ItemsCounting()
> ^
> }, void 0, false, {
> fileName: _jsxFileName,
> lineNumber: 15,

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes it has worked. Thanks to you.

Now i am not getting the output in the console.

Comment: const length = this.state.movies.length()

        console.log(length)

It should return the output

Comment: console is printing 'hello' but not the length. I think that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`length` is a array *property*, not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

Use

```
const length = this.state.movies.length;
```

or use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const { length } = this.state.movies;
```

Additionally `ItemsNumber` doesn't require its own state. Simply return the length of the array that you pass in as a component property.

Be mindful that when you use a real asynchronous call to an API you'll have to check that the movies array exists first.

```
class ItemsNumber extends Component {

  render(props) {

    const { length } = this.props.movies;

    if (!length) return <div />;

    return <div>{length}</div>;

  }

}
```